# How to insert data in database using java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've trying to `insert data` in db  using `my sql`.  string from where to getting data and inserting in db.

**String is  :**

```
s=
1 kalim khan NIL    
2 ajay sharma NIL   
3 navneet gupta  NIL    
4 amar kumar srivastava NIL
```

I want that where spaces are more then 3 that should `skiped` and `moved` ahead

**the code is following as:**

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(htmlTableText);
   while(str.hasMoreElements()){
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
          int sno = Integer.parseInt(str.nextElement().toString());

        String fname = str.nextElement().toString();
        String lname = str.nextElement().toString();
        String price = str.nextElement().toString();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection  cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mandi","root","");
         //insert them into the database
         PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("insert into commoditywise  values(?,?,?,?)");
         ps.setInt(1,sno);
         ps.setString(2, fname);
         ps.setString(3, lname);
         ps.setString(4, price);
            int j =ps.executeUpdate();
            if(j==1)
            {
            System.out.println("data inserted");
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.println("not inserted");
            }
      }
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can *inset* it by using some sort of query.

Comment: how can i could u  tell me

Comment: Small Tip: `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class. Try using the `String.split()` instead.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ How can i could u please write

Comment: @user3496498 - [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/2024761).

Comment: Please describe the actual problem you have, don't make us guess.

Comment: my actual prom is only this that where string is having more then three prob  skip that string thats it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe StringTokenizer's count method can help you?

```
int count = str.countTokens();
if (count > 4) {
   continue;
}
```

Otherwise I would just insert the first strings until I get to the last name.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps.setInt(1,sno);
ps.setString(2,fname);
ps.setString(3,lname);
ps.setString(4,price);
```

There is some error in these lines,

Solution: **Use DTO ( Setter and Getter method class / bean class)** to get sno,fname,lname,price values

try this 
 here              1.dtoclassname= your bean class ( setter   and setter method class)
2.getSno() = is method for getting value.

```
ps.setInt(1,dtoclassname.getSno());
```

do above said operations for other fields.